# 既存のPHPアプリ(nextcloud)と新しく作るASP.NET Core (Kestrel)が共存できない

Tags: apache

**やりたいこと：**
`https://example.com/siteA`   nextcloud
`https://example.com/siteB`   ASP.NET Core (Kestrel)
この2つを同時に稼働させたい。

**現状：**
この状態だと、siteAへのHTTPSによる接続は上手く行き、ちゃんと稼働しています。
siteBへの接続は404NotFoundです。
この時、Kestrelを直接curlで接続してみると、想定していた出力がされていることを確認しました。

次に、siteB.confの<VirtualHost *:80>を<VirtualHost *:443>に変更すると、今度はsiteBが正しく表示され、
siteAが404NotFoundで表示されなくなります。

443にしたときに、443ポートへの接続がくるとsiteB側の設定だけが適用されている様に見えるのですが、実際の所、どうしてこうなるのかがわかっていません。
どうにか両立するようにできないでしょうか？

**システム**
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
dotnet: 3.1.401
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

### /conf.d/rewrite.conf

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://hogehoge.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</ifModule>
```

### /conf.d/siteA.conf

```
Https
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hogehoge.com
  ServerAdmin admin@hogehoge.com
  DocumentRoot /home/www/html/siteA/
  <directory /home/www/html/siteA>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
#    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HOME /home/www/html/siteA
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /home/www/html/siteA
  </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### /conf.d/siteB.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName hogehoge.com
        DocumentRoot /home/www/siteB
        <Directory "/home/www/siteB">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass /siteB http://localhost:5000/siteB
        ProxyPassReverse /siteB http://localhost:5000/siteB
        SSLEngine on
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!RC4
        SSLCertificateFile zzz/ssl.crt/xxxxxx.rcrt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile zzz/ssl.key/xxxxxx.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile zzz/ssl.crt/yyyyy.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

---

2020/09/09
追記
発想を変えることにしました。
現在nextcloudが稼働しているApacheサーバをPHP用アプリケーションサーバとみなして、nginxサーバを新たにリバースプロキシサーバに当てました。

Apacheを停止後、Listenに新たなHTTP,HTTPS用ポートを割り当て。
Nginxサーバをインストール後、

```
    location /siteA{
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5003;
        ...
    }
    location /siteB{
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    }
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

    }
```

この構成でNginx,Apache,kestrelをそれぞれ起動した所、siteA、siteBの双方に想定していたアクセスを得る事ができました。
nextcloud側はSSL設定していないのでBadRequestで弾かれますが、nginx側で設定していないので想定通りの動作と言えます。
localhostで稼働するバックグラウンドサーバのSSL設定等まだ考える必要はありますが、現在この方向で検証しています。

Comment: もしかしたら、追記での対策と同様のことがこちらのページに記述されているのかもしれません。[Nginx 搭載の Linux で ASP.NET Core をホストする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1), [Apache 搭載の Linux で ASP.NET Core をホストする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: ぐるっと一周した感はありますが、プロクシサーバとして立てたNginxにそのままPHP関連移植できそうなんですよね。Apacheではリバースプロキシ…というか、VirtualHostという管理単位を考えると、サブドメインで切り分けるのが正しい運用に見えます。私がやろうとしていたサブディレクトリを公式ドキュメントでやろうとすると、上手く行かないのは理解できます。Nginxの方が素直に感じました。

Comment: 現状、プロキシに対するSSLの設定、X-ヘッダー群、Content-Security-Policyをドキュメントを参考にしながら各アプリケーションサーバに合わせて設定して、問題なくそれぞれのサーバが稼働することを確認しています。
編集やコメント助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ApacheでもLocationディレクティブ上手く使ったら行けそうではあるのですが…要勉強ですね。

Comment: 情報共有と解決済みの印に、追記の部分やその後も含めて対処した内容を自己回答として分割・承認してください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

望んでいた動作にすることができました。
以下、概要と設定ファイルです。

Apacheでリバースプロキシを行う場合、VirtualHostはホストとポートで切り分けるための仕組みなので、
正しくはサブドメインで切り分けるのが正しいと判断しました。
そこで、新たにリバースプロキシサーバとしてNginxを構築し、その配下にApacheとKestrelをぶら下げることにしました。
Apacheはポート変更とSSLの停止を行っています。SSL化はプロキシにまとめました。

実際に試してみた所、動作自体はすぐにできました。
問題点としては、プロキシ側で適切なHTTPヘッダーを設定してあげないとセキュリティ的に問題があったり、
読み込めない画像があったりだったので、その辺の対応も入っています。

**nginx/conf.d/server.conf**(default.conf)

```
upstream siteB{
    #kestrel
    server localhost:5000;
}

upstream siteA{
    #apache
    server localhost:5003;
}
server {
    listen     *:80;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        return     301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       *:443 ssl;
    server_name  hogehoge.com;

    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate           /xxx/yyyy/zzzz/ssl.crt/nginx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /xxx/yyyy/zzzz//ssl.key/server.key;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers               "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    ssl_ecdh_curve            secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets       off;
    ssl_stapling              on; 
    ssl_stapling_verify       on; 

    location /siteB {
        proxy_pass         http://siteB;
        limit_req zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
        keepalive_timeout 75s;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header  Content-Security-Policy " default-src 'self' data: gap: ; form-action 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';frame-src 'self' *.twitter.com *.facebook.com www.youtube.com; img-src 'self' * data: blob:; media-src 'self' *.youtube.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://use.fontawesome.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' * data: blob: fonts.gstatic.com https://use.fontawesome.com; object-src 'none' ";
    }
    location /siteA {
        proxy_pass         http://siteA;
        limit_req zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
        keepalive_timeout 75s;
            add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
            add_header X-Download-Options "noopen" always;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none" always;
            add_header X-Robots-Tag "none" always;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
            add_header  Content-Security-Policy " default-src 'self' data: gap: ; form-action 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' * data: blob:; media-src 'self' *.youtube.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; object-src 'none' ";
    }
    location /otherApp {
        proxy_pass    http://localhost:5003;
        limit_req zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
            add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
            add_header X-Download-Options "noopen" always;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none" always;
            add_header X-Robots-Tag "none" always;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    }
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

    }

    #
    #以下、省略
    #
}
```

**nginx/proxy.conf**

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
```

**nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
    server_tokens off;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: 補記：
limit_req zone=one burst=10 nodelay;はnextcloudにおいてburst値がたりないです。
burst=200が余裕あって良い値です。そのくらいバンバンリクエストするので。